# Intel Xeon processors: Difference between 2S/4S and S2S/S4S scalability

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit, scalability, xeon

While comparing Intel Xeon E5 and E7 processors, I've noticed that E5 processors are specified for 2S or 4S scalability, while E7 processors are specified for **S**2S, **S**4S, or **S**8S scalability.

I understand that the processors are specified for use in up to the given number of sockets on the same motherboard, but what does the extra S actually mean? What's the difference between 2S and S2S, and between 4S and S4S?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference between S4S and 4S is the number of QPI-Links. 4S has 2 links per CPU, S4S and S8S have 3.

On a 4S system CPUs form a ring, which means for every CPU there is another CPU with which it can only communicate indirectly, because it is only connected to 2 CPUs via QPI.

On S4S every CPU is directly connected to every other CPU.

For S8S there are also 3 QPI links.

Question is a little older, but maybe my answer is still relevant.

Comment: By the way:
You can use 4S as well as (theoretically) S4S CPUs in a compatible dual-socket system.
However, there is no meaningful reason to do so with the expensive S4S (currently E7-4800), as they use their own socket (2011-1) and you probably won't find a dual socket mainboard for them.

What might be true (can't confirm though) is that running 2 or 3 CPUs in a 4-Socket Mainboard might only work with S4S.

Answer (score 12):

Based on "6.5.8.4 MPSUP: Multiprocessor Support" in [Intel® Xeon® Processor E7-4800/8800 v3 Product Families; Datasheet - Volume 1: Electrical, Mechanical and Thermal](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/xeon-e7-v3-datasheet-vol-1.pdf) (pdf, page 139):

> This location contains 2 bits for representing the supported number of physical processors on the bus. These two bits are LSB aligned where 00b equates to nonscalable 2 socket (2S) operation, 01b to scalable 2 socket (S2S), 10 to scalable 4 socket (S4S), and scalable 8 socket (S8S). The Intel® Xeon® E7 v3 processor is a S2S, S4S, or S8S processor. The first six bits in this field are reserved for future use. Writes to this register have no effect.

- `S` prefix:

  - Exists: Scalable (based on the language, I believe this means you can use fewer processors)
  - Missing: Nonscalable (you must have the specified number of processors)
- Number:

  - Number of processors (if scalable, this is maximum number of processors; if nonscalable, this is the required number of processors)
- `S` postfix:

  - Stands for "socket"

So, for example, `S4S` is "scalable four socket" and `2S` is "nonscalable two socket".